# RabbitMQ, .NET Core and Kubernetes (configuration)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, rabbitmq

I'm trying to set up a few micro services in Kubernetes. Everything is working as expected, except the connection from one micro service to RabbitMQ.

Problem flow:

- .NET Core app --> rabbitmq-kubernetes-service.yml --> RabbitMQ

In the .NET Core app the rabbit connection factory config looks like this:

```
"RabbitMQ": {
    "Host": "rabbitmq-service",
    "Port": 7000,
    "UserName": "guest",
    "Password": "guest"
}
```

The kubernetes rabbit service looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
    - port: 7000
      targetPort: 5672
```

As well as the rabbit deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: <private ACR with vanilla cfg - the image is: rabbitmq:3.7.9-management-alpine>
          imagePullPolicy: Always        
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 512Mi
            requests:
              cpu: "0.5"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5672
```

So this setup is currently **not** working in k8s. Locally it works like a charm with a basic docker-compose.

*However*, what I can do in k8s is to go from a LoadBalancer --> to the running rabbit pod and access the management GUI with these config settings.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmqmanagement-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 15672
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are running the `.NET Core app` outside the Kubernetes cluster.
If this is indeed the case then you need to use `type: LoadBalancer`.

**[LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)** is used to expose a service to the internet.

**ClusterIP** exposes the service inside cluster-internal IP. So `Service` will be only accessible from within the cluster, also this is a default `ServiceType`.

**[NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)** exposes the service on each Node's IP at a static port.

For more details regarding Services please check the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service).

You can if the connection is working using a python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host='RABBITMQ_SERVER_IP'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

This script will try to connect `RABBITMQ_SERVER_IP` using port `5672`.

Script requires a library [`pika`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which can be installed using `pip install pika`.